# Why can "Java Concurrency in Practice Listing 10.5." produce a complete snapshot?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading *Java Concurrency in Practice* and encounter the following code snippet.

```
// Listing 10.5. Lock-ordering deadlock between cooperating objects. Don’t do this.

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

// Warning: deadlock-prone!
class Taxi {
    @GuardedBy("this")
    private Point location, destination;
    private final Dispatcher dispatcher;

    public Taxi(Dispatcher dispatcher) {
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }

    public synchronized Point getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public synchronized void setLocation(Point location) {
        this.location = location;
        if (location.equals(destination))
            dispatcher.notifyAvailable(this);
    }
}

class Dispatcher {
    @GuardedBy("this")
    private final Set<Taxi> taxis;
    @GuardedBy("this")
    private final Set<Taxi> availableTaxis;

    public Dispatcher() {
        taxis = new HashSet<Taxi>();
        availableTaxis = new HashSet<Taxi>();
    }

    public synchronized void notifyAvailable(Taxi taxi) {
        availableTaxis.add(taxi);
    }

    public synchronized Image getImage() {
        Image image = new Image();
        for (Taxi t : taxis)
            image.drawMarker(t.getLocation());
        return image;
    }
}
```

It then says:

> In the deadlock-prone version, getImage produces a complete snapshot of the fleet locations at that instant.

When calling `getImage`, we get Dispatcher's intrinsic lock, other threads can't modify `taxis`, **but** other threads can still modify the `location` of `Taxi` although the thread calling `getImage` **might not** see the change. So, **why can `getImage` produces a complete snapshot of the fleet locations at that instant?**

Comment: emm, a current location is a different thing from current destination?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. Both`setLocation` and `getImage` access `location`.

Comment: You've mentioned `destination` in question as the variable which could be modified and the `getImage` could not see that change. `getImage` doesnt uses `destination` and later all the `getImage, getLocation and setLocation` are synchronized. The last **bold** part of your question asks about image of locations which arent using `destination` anywhere.

Comment: I have edited the question body, change `destination` to `location`.

Comment: all the methods using `location` variable are synchronized

Comment: Yes, but the intrinsic lock of `Dispatcher` is different from intrinsic lock of `Taxi`.

Answer (score 0):

The thread calling `getImage` will see the location change. When I read

> produces a complete snapshot of the snapshot locations at that instant

I interpreted it to mean that from the moment `getImage` starts executing the locations of the taxis can't change, but they can - via the call to `setLocation` in `Taxi` - and these changes will be visible